# How to interpret suggestions when installing CakePHP via Composer?

Tags: cakephp, composer-php

When I try installing with command line:

```
composer self-update && composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app my_app_name
```

I keep getting this message, which I didnt use to have, now which one is required, which one is not, do I have to download manually everytime?

```
cakephp/app suggests installing markstory/asset_compress (An asset compression plugin which provides file concatenation and a flexible filter system for preprocessing and minification.)
cakephp/app suggests installing dereuromark/cakephp-ide-helper (After baking your code, this keeps your annotations in sync with the code evolving from there on for maximum IDE and PHPStan compatibility.)
cakephp/app suggests installing phpunit/phpunit (Allows automated tests to be run without system-wide install.)
cakephp/cakephp suggests installing lib-ICU (The intl PHP library, to use Text::transliterate() or Text::slug())
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/event-dispatcher ()
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/lock ()
symfony/console suggests installing psr/log-implementation (For using the console logger)
m1/env suggests installing m1/vars (For loading of configs)
asm89/twig-cache-extension suggests installing psr/cache-implementation (To make use of PSR-6 cache implementation via PsrCacheAdapter.)
aptoma/twig-markdown suggests installing michelf/php-markdown (Original Markdown engine with MarkdownExtra.)
aptoma/twig-markdown suggests installing knplabs/github-api (Needed for using GitHub's Markdown engine provided through their API.)
ajgl/breakpoint-twig-extension suggests installing ext-xdebug (The Xdebug extension is required for the breakpoint to work)
ajgl/breakpoint-twig-extension suggests installing symfony/framework-bundle (The framework bundle to integrate the extension into Symfony)
ajgl/breakpoint-twig-extension suggests installing symfony/twig-bundle (The twig bundle to integrate the extension into Symfony)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pcntl (Enabling the PCNTL extension makes PsySH a lot happier :))
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-posix (If you have PCNTL, you'll want the POSIX extension as well.)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A pure PHP readline implementation. You'll want this if your PHP install doesn't already support readline or libedit.)
```

Comment: None of them are required, they're just suggestions. If you feel that a particular project would benefit from one or more of them, then install those. It will be on a project-by-project basis, though, because the needs of each project vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are only suggestions that may extend the functionality of already installed packages, but everything should work fine without them. For example `monolog/monolog` will suggest a couple of plugins that will allow logging into different backends. But `monolog/monolog` will work without them - you may not be able to log for example to Sentry, but `monolog` will still be usable without this feature.

So usually you can just ignore these suggestions. But you can take a few minutes to check what these suggested packages are actually doing - you can learn about new technologies and solutions that can make your app better and easier to maintain.

If you're really not interested in these suggestions, you can use `--no-suggest` switch to avoid displaying them on `install`/`update`/`require`:

```
composer install --no-suggest
```